# VBA to clear files from microsoft access

Tags: excel, vba

Please advise as to how to remove recent file history from Microsoft access. Below coding is clearing history from excel but I want to clear it from MS access.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim i As Integer
  For i = 1 To Application.RecentFiles.Count
   Application.RecentFiles(i).Delete
  Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe not possible, review https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834420.aspx. See the Note.

Comment: Or maybe have to go 'old school' route https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862548.aspx